# load another page while ajax still running / lock page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dom

I have problem about ajax jquery and CI.

The problem is, for example, like I have 2 menu:

1. profile
2. add new profile

First time when I open page profile, Ajax loads the data, while Ajax status is still pending I hit the menu "add new profile" to open in new tab. And the result is the 2nd page "add new profile" has already opened but the page is not loaded (blank white page). 
After the Ajax loaded in menu 1, the 2nd page just started to load the page.

So is there any solution to load the page without waiting the Ajax jQuery done?

Comment: you can use tow parallel trade to run  both ajax request together. you can user setTimeout to make new trade

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. i already found what i am missing.. session_write_close(); in controller CI

Answer (score 5):

your $ajax call is calling asynchronously ..try async:false of $ajax call.